# User IP For Curl Instead Of Server IP

Tags: php, php-curl

I have the code below in one of my scripts but every time it runs it uses my IP address. How I can make it use the IP address of the user? I was reading about `curl_setopt()` which allows you to set the IP address. Can someone assist me with that?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '' . $stuff_link[0] . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '' . $stuff_refurl . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is: you cant do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is - fortunately - impossible.

In fact, you can if your user has an [http proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) installed...